# Get window title from Twitter.com after a link is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

Twitter.com opens a new window after a link is clicked in a status update. Is there any way to get the title of the window opener meaning the Twitter page the link originated from? I want to then send this title to PHP for further processing.

Comment: What programming language are you hoping to use for this?

Comment: PHP, Javascript or a combination of both.

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing the title is being obstructed by the two re-directs. Can this be accomplished through Sessions/Cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
alert(window.opener.document.title);
```

I believe that will give you the parent window's title.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
if (window.opener != null) {

    alert("works?");
    alert(window.opener.document.title);

} else {

    alert("You're screwed.");

}
```

Comment: See my edit. If window.opener is null in your situation, you're out of luck.

Comment: interestingly, still no alert box. Im writing the following code to test.php which is a view loaded by codeigniter. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
 if (window.opener != null) {

    alert(window.opener.document.title);

} else {

    alert("You're screwed.");

}
</script> 
  
</body>
</html>`

Comment: when I write `alert("Am I screwed?")` , I get an alert box.

Comment: Ok, my guess would be that there is a browser issue that is causing it to suppress the second alert. This could be related to security policies of the browser your using due to the fact that you're trying to access the document of completely different domain. What you're needing to do may not be possible in this case.